# Open XML SDK 2.5 + SharePoint 2013 - docx-file empty

Tags: sharepoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to generate a simple docx-file in SharePoint 2013 using Open XML SDK 2.5.

My function successfully generates a docx-file in the SharePoint-library, but when I try to open it, it is empty or corrupt. 
I already tried a lot and used different technics I found here and in the web.

```
 protected void generateDoc(string docName)
    {
        SPWeb spWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

        spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        spWeb.Lists.IncludeRootFolder = true;

        SPList docLib = spWeb.Lists["test"];
        string fileUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Site, "/test/" + docName);

        SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated elevatedSubmit = new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(delegate
        {
            // MediaStream erstellen
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create a Wordprocessing document.
                using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                {
                    // Add a new main document part. 
                    package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    // Create the Document DOM. 
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(new Body());
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(
                           new Paragraph(
                             new Run(
                               new Text("TEST"))));

                    ms.Position = 0;
                    byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

                    SPFile file = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, ms, true);
                    file.Update();
                }
            }
        });
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(elevatedSubmit);
    }
```

It would be nice if somebody could give me a hint.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are trying to read the content before its written. So it wont contain any data.
Remove and put the following code from the second **using** to the end of first **using**.

```
ms.Position = 0;
byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
SPFile file = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, ms, true);
file.Update();
```

for getting the content to the byte array.
The modified code will be

```
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create a Wordprocessing document.
                using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                {
                    // Add a new main document part. 
                    package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    // Create the Document DOM. 
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(new Body());
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(
                           new Paragraph(
                             new Run(
                               new Text("TEST"))));

                    //package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

                }
                ms.Position = 0;
                byte[] content = ms.ToArray();SPFile file = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, ms, true);
file.Update();

            }
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that instead of fabricating a document from scratch, you start with an empty document and add the content that you want to it.  This is a much more reliable way to proceed.  You can store the binary document in an embedded resource, or you can embed the document directly in your C# code, as shown in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/28/creating-a-template-open-xml-document-in-memory.aspx).

Another important hint - instead of writing the C# code yourself, use the document reflector capabilities of the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool.  It can take any document, or any part of a document, or any element in any part, and generate valid C# code that you can use in your application.  You can find a demo of the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool in the "Tools" screen-cast that you can find in these [Introduction to Open XML screen-casts](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/introduction-to-open-xml.aspx).  You should also be familiar with the other interesting tools, including the [Open XML Package Editor PowerTool for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xKcR8YIhlA) (this is a vital tool).  You may want to view the other screen-casts in that series as well.

After viewing the screen-casts on Open XML in general, you may want to view [these screen-casts on WordprocessingML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/introduction-to-wordprocessingml.aspx).

Cheers, Eric

Comment: thanks. I will check out the Power Tool and way to store the binaries. It looks very interesting.  I know I can use the Productivity Tool to autogenerate the Open XML part, but if I use it for a document with just "Test"-Text it generates huge amounts of code. I just wanted to write a clean and small solution so I can be sure I understand how it works.